# Invert mouse cursor color?

Tags: ubuntu, accessibility, mouse-cursor

Windows 10 allows for global mouse pointer color inversion in the Ease of Access Center. How can I have this in Ubuntu perhaps using the compositor?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Seems like this isn't possible : [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224430/invert-mouse-colour).

Comment: Would this help? "Chameleon Xcursors... The cursors border color is negative of body color for high visibility." https://www.gnome-look.org/p/999948 See also https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=256427